# xcode set the other linker flag

Tags: ios, xcode, hyperlink, compilation

The environment:
1. xcode7.3.1
2. mac os 10.11.4
3. support ARC

I write the file that is a category of UIView, and its name is 'UIView+Frame'.

```
- (CGFloat)centerX
{
    return self.centerX;
}

- (void)setCenterX:(CGFloat)centerX
{
    CGPoint center = self.center;
    center.x = centerX;
    self.center = center;
}
```

I use the 3rd static library, when i set the '-all_load' at other linker flag of build setting, the 3rd static library can't be linked, it tell me duplicate symbols and it fails.

But i cancel the flag of '-all_load', the 3rd static library can be linked and successfully.Badly, the category of 'UIView+Frame' has a crash when call centerX.

I can't resolve the problem, please help me, thanks.

Comment: Could you help us providing the crash log you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has resolved this problem.

```
- (CGFloat)centerX
{
    return self.centerX;
}
```

Modify it as follow

```
- (CGFloat)centerX
{
    return self.center.x;
}
```

Comment: That is completely unrelated to your incomplete question.